# adding onClick event to show a hidden div above each bar in D3.js (maybe I'm missing important css code also?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

So what I'm trying to do is to have a hidden div, called myDiv, to show up above the clicked bar when each squared bar is clicked.

What I've tried so far is 
1) Javascript code for showDiv()

```js
 function showDiv() {
     document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "block";
 }
```

2) HTML code for myDiv

```html
<div id= "myDiv" style="display: none;">
     <p>Detail</p>
</div>
```

3) CSS for a bar chart

```css
div.bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;   /* Gets overriden by D3-assigned height below */
    margin-right: 2px;
```

4) Javascript (D3) code for onClick event on a bar

```js
var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 7, 21, 24, 15, 16];
var bar = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .style("height", function(d) {
                var barHeight = d * 5;
                return barHeight + "px";
            })
            .style("width", function(d) {
                var barWidth = d * 5;
                return barWidth + "px";
            })
           .on("click", showDiv);
```

With what I already have show up at an on click event of a bar.
But I'm not sure how I can make myDiv to appear above a selected bar.

Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you should look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It's a Javascript library that makes dom manipulation and traversal much easier.

I see that you have the showDiv function working, but now need to make it show only the myDiv above the clicked item. Without your full html markup it's a bit hard to know what you mean. However, looking into the jQuery API for dom traversal might help. For example, [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for. I just didn't know which direction to go to.

Answer (score 0):

In your `showDiv()` function, your element ID has a lowercase 'm'. The actual element has an uppercase 'M'. That will cause it to not work. Unless that's a typo?

If that doesn't answer both questions, sorry, but that's the most I can help. I don't know anything about D3.

Comment: omg! I changed Mydiv to myDiv and now the div shows up! haha. Thanks! I've edited my question. I still need help figuring out myDiv to show up above a selected bar.